# How to delete an Item from an SQL table based on user entry?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to store items, urls and prices within a MySQL database and wanted to give the user the option to delete the item based on the name. I am trying to do this by using a DELETE sql statement but it just returns "0 item removed" and I am guessing it is not able to find the entry, whether that be that it is not taking the input or what. Any help would be appreciated as I would really like to get the hang of this!

```
def deleteItem(): 
    goneItem = input("Enter item: ")
    removeItem = "DELETE FROM amazon_items WHERE itemName = '%s'"
    mycursor.execute(removeItem, goneItem)
    db.commit()
    print(mycursor.rowcount, "item removed")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi LearningCode welcome to stackoverflow,

```
mycursor.execute(removeItem, (goneItem,))
```

Try this one.

You can see in [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) in the documentation you need to include a comma to make the second argument a tuple.

Comment: Hello. Thankyou for the help! After making the change you suggested I was still finding an error that there was an issue and would display 'itemname''' in the error. I guess part of the issue was the way i was using double quotes and that was causing a problem with it so had to change the query to 'query' instead of "query".

Comment: In the process of changing the Python string literal's quotes I assume you removed the quotes around `%s`? That was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the single quote around `%s` and you should pass the value for `%s` as a tuple

```
def deleteItem(): 
    goneItem = input("Enter item: ")
    removeItem = "DELETE FROM amazon_items WHERE itemName = %s"
    mycursor.execute(removeItem, (goneItem,))
    db.commit()
    print(mycursor.rowcount, "item removed")
```